# Setting the volume of target process using win32 waveOutSetVolume function?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, audio, pinvoke

I would like to set the volume of an specified process that is playing audio.

I found that I can do it with the `waveOutSetVolume` WinAPI function because it works as per-process, however, after I read these docs below I still can't figure out how to do it.

- **[waveOutSetVolume function - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**
- **[waveOutSetVolume function - pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm.waveoutsetvolume)**

I'm searching for a solution in C# or VB.Net.

This is the firm of my `waveOutSetVolume`:

```
<DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint:="waveOutSetVolume", SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Shared Function WaveOutSetVolume(byval hwo As IntPtr, 
                                        byval dwVolume As UInteger) As Integer
End Function
```

And this is how I'm trying to call the function:

```
Public Sub SetVolume(ByVal hwo As IntPtr, ByVal volume As Integer)

    If (volume < 0) OrElse (volume > 100) Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                  paramName:="volume", 
                  message:="A value between 0 and 100 is required.")

    Else
       Dim valueFromPercent As UShort = CUShort(volume / (100US / UShort.MaxValue))

       ' Left channel volume
        Dim loBytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(valueFromPercent)

       ' Right channel volume
        Dim hiBytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(valueFromPercent)

        Dim dWord As UInteger = 
            BitConverter.ToUInt32(loBytes.Concat(hiBytes).ToArray, 0)

        NativeMethods.WaveOutSetVolume(hwo, dWord)

    End If

End Sub
```

I know that an hwo will not be the same as a process handle, but as I said I can't figure it out how to discover the hwo of a process.

Note my DWORD calculation seems not be the problem because if I pass a `Intptr.Zero` to the function then it sets the expected volume for the **current** application.

Comment: To the phantom downvoter, would you like to explain why a question like this can deserve a downvote?.

Comment: Most likely you'll have to create one in your process e.g. using [waveOutOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743866(v=vs.85).aspx) (possibly other additional tasks involved), or enumerate available compatible devices, and pass the device ID.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for comment, but note that I can set the volume of the caller application without using additional functions like **waveOutOpen**, or maybe I missunderstood and what you mean is use that function from my app to open/access the wave-form of other application?.

Comment: The downvote could be because what you are trying to do is not possible, it would be like changing the way Windows renders a button inside a process, from an external process. You can do something like this in your own application, you can modify both applications so that they communicate and then have the second process modify its own volume, but that's the best you can achieve.

Comment: You're right, I was the one that misunderstood the question. I am not aware of any way to get the hwo from a specified process (but i think that's something internal for that process, and even if you did you couldn't do anything with it). I am imagining some kind of a workaround, to create a hwo, get the device id associated with it, and operate on that device and (I only assume here) all the hwos that are linked to the device id.